# How can I beat Alduin at the throat of the world?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am stuck. Simply put, I have been relying completely on my vampire lord form, as it is OP is heck now (All Perks). Now I realize it is completely ineffective on Alduin and barely nicks at his health. Now I cannot even stand there for 5 seconds before I die. Is there any way that I can overpower him without dying? Any suggestions are welcome. Literally anything.

Comment: You're not meant to beat him at the Throat of the World. If I remember correctly, you kill Alduin in Sovngarde, and you have help doing it.

Comment: Do you have any skills other than your vampire lord form? What are your highest offensive skills? Do you have weapons? A bow? Do you have a follower?

Comment: Do you have trouble with other dragons?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf yes, but you need to defeat him at the throat before killing him in Sovngarde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, Alduin is invulnerable while flying. You MUST use dragonrend to make him land before you can damage him.

Now, as a vampire, you are extremely vulnerable to fire, but not so much to cold. Alduin uses both fire and ice breath. You should consider enchanting your items with "resist fire" to deal with his fire breath. A potion to resist fire is also helpful.

If Alduin is summoning meteor showers, you can use Clear Sky to clear the meteor showers. Otherwise, you should use the first word of dragonrend as much as possible on Alduin. It staggers him every time.

You want to position yourself at his side, near his wings. This triggers his wing-slams, which deals the least amount of damage.

Having a companion and summons is helpful, as they can tank for you.

If you have no good weapon, there is a sword called dragonbane in Sky Haven Temple. It is extra good against dragons. You can get another one handed weapon so you can duel-wield for more damage.

You can see a fight [here](https://youtu.be/ulYNPbuga_g?t=28m44s).

Finally, you can turn down the difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't fully defeat Alduin during [Alduin's Bane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alduin%27s_Bane), but you do need to do enough damage to make him run away. The best strategy for doing this is going to depend on what your character can do outside of turning into a vampire.

Regardless of what you can do yourself, though, there's always a follower. If you bring an essential follower, like [Mjoll](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mjoll_the_Lioness), then they ought to be able to fight Alduin while you hide. This will take a while, but they will just keep getting back up.

Otherwise, just use Dragonrend and hit him with ranged attacks while cowering behind cover, or use something that stuns him from close range, like shield bashes or a paralyze weapon.

Answer (score 0):

you're not supposed to defeat Alduin there, you'll only beat him some and he will fly away. Use Dragonrend, maybe pop some potions before transforming (or don't transform at all and work around your "human" perks instead). With a decent weapon/bow you'll make him run in no time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a good follower like mjoll and outfit her with the best armor you can find they will tank for you and you will be able to defeat him with a few extra helpers (summons and a pet )